# creating a zf2 module without controllers with some autoloaded classes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-loader

I'm trying to create a Zend Framework 2 module that has some generic classes that I want to use in some of my controllers.

I created a directory called 'tux-drink-zf2-module' in 'vendor' directory.

I added that directory to 'application.config.php'.

my Module.php has the following:

```
<?php

namespace TuxDrink;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
}
```

## update

new:

my autoload_classmap.php has the following:

```
<?php
// Generated by ZF2's ./bin/classmap_generator.php
return array(
'TuxDrink\Module'                                  => __DIR__ . '/Module.php',
'TuxDbCassandra'                                   => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Cassandra/TuxDbCassandra.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\AlcoholSum'                  => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/AlcoholSum.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\AlcoholSumTable'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/AlcoholSumTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\Drink'                       => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/Drink.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkBrand'                  => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkBrand.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkBrandTable'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkBrandTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkCompany'                => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkCompany.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkCompanyTable'           => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkCompanyTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkFlavor'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkFlavor.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkFlavorTable'            => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkFlavorTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkFlavorType'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkFlavorType.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkFlavorTypeTable'        => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkFlavorTypeTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkIngredient'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkIngredient.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkIngredientTable'        => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkIngredientTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkIngredientType'         => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkIngredientType.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkIngredientTypeTable'    => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkIngredientTypeTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkTable'                  => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkType'                   => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkType.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\DrinkTypeTable'              => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/DrinkTypeTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImage'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImage.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageLink'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageLink.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageLinkPending'      => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageLinkPending.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageLinkPendingTable' => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageLinkPendingTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageLinkTable'        => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageLinkTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageTable'            => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageType'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageType.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\GlobalImageTypeTable'        => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/GlobalImageTypeTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\LiquidColor'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/LiquidColor.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\LiquidColorTable'            => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/LiquidColorTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\LiquidColorType'             => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/LiquidColorType.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\LiquidColorTypeTable'        => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/LiquidColorTypeTable.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\PendingDrinkCommits'         => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/PendingDrinkCommits.php',
'TuxDrink\Drink\Model\PendingDrinkCommitsTable'    => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Model/PendingDrinkCommitsTable.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\Mysql\Drink\TuxDbMysqlDrink'       => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/TuxDbMysqlDrink.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\Drink\Util\AlcoholCalc'            => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/Drink/Util/AlcoholCalc.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\Mysql\TuxDbMysql'                  => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/Mysql/TuxDbMysql.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\TuxDbAbstract'                     => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/TuxDbAbstract.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\TuxDbInterface'                    => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/TuxDbInterface.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\TuxDrinkInterface'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/TuxDrinkInterface.php',
'TuxDrink\TuxDb\TuxTableInterface'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/TuxDrink/TuxDb/TuxTableInterface.php',
);
```

but still when I try to refresh my project I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (tux-drink-zf2-module) could not be initialized.' in /Volumes/2g-storage/projects/php-projects/myalcoholist/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 144
```

maybe i'm missing some other files in order to properly configure this as a Module?
remember, this is a package for sources, without controllers, views and actions.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

this issue was solved when i fixed the directories structure.

but when I'm trying to use the module in one the the controllers.

in my case i need to use two classes from the TuxDrink module.

class 'TuxDbMysqlDrink' and class 'TuxDbMysql'.

I need to use them in controller 'DrinkController' in action 'drink-brand-autocomplete'.

I use the following code:

```
use \TuxDb\Mysql\Drink\TuxDbMysqlDrink;

use \TuxDb\Mysql\TuxDbMysql;


public function drinkBrandAutocompleteAction() {
    $param=$this->getRequest()->getQuery('q');
    if ($param) {
        $drink = new TuxDbMysqlDrink();
        $result=$drink->autoCompleteDrinkBrand($param);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

and I get the following error message:

```
 Fatal error: DrinkManagement\Controller\DrinkController cannot use TuxDrink\TuxDb\Mysql\Drink\TuxDbMysqlDrink - it is not a trait in /Volumes/2g-storage/projects/php-projects/myalcoholist/module/DrinkManagement/src/DrinkManagement/Controller/DrinkController.php on line 197
```

any ideas?

tried to google, couldn't understand what it means "it is not a trait"

## update

resolved it with this code:

```
public function drinkBrandAutocompleteAction() {
    $param=$this->getRequest()->getQuery('q');
    if ($param) {
        $drink = new \TuxDrink\TuxDb\Mysql\Drink\TuxDbMysqlDrink();
        $result=$drink->autoCompleteDrinkBrand($param);
        die(var_export($result,1));
     ...
```

Comment: ok it seems that it's related to namespaces issues. checking it now.

Comment: __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__, <- it's not in this structure

Comment: ok it's not related. i fixed the sources to be in src/TuxDrink and recreated autoload_classmap.php and problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the error, the Module name is `tux-drink-zf2-module`. Taking sanitization into account, i'll assume your module is CamelCased like `TuxDrinkZf2Module`. Therefore the namespace you're assigning inside `Module.php` doesn't match, as it's only `TuxDrink`.

So my guess would be, either of your names is incorrect.

Comment: the directory name inside vendor is named tux-drink-zf2-module

Comment: i renamed the directory to TuxDrink and i'm not getting the error anymore! :) i'll continue and see how can i use the classes anymore. hopefully the issue is resolved

Comment: of course i also changed the name of the module to TuxDrink in application.config.php